# Best way to communicate between NodeJs and C child process

Tags: c, node.js, sockets, ipc

I want to pass messages between a Node.js server and a C program that is forked by the Nodejs server. I know there are a lot of possibilities. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39841942/communicating-between-nodejs-and-c-using-node-ipc-and-unix-sockets) is one on StackOverflow. However, I want the lightest possible  mechanism as the server passes one message to the Child process at the start and the Child process sends one at the end. What would be the **lightest** possible solution for this?

I can think of TCP, UDP, pipes, Unix sockets or just writing to a file and reading from it. TCP sockets would be a heavy solution.

Any suggestion?

Comment: There is no reason to use TCP if you can use Unix d. sockets.

Comment: There is no "best" way.  You can pick any one of several options that meet your needs.  stdin and stdout are probably the most generic, but you could also setup several other methods.

Comment: Similar question [Interprocess communication between node and c applicatoin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16779806/inter-process-communication-between-node-and-c-application) and a module for this [node-ipc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ipc).  Google is your friend.  Lots of other things to read.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've spawned your child process `p` you can send it input via STDIN using `p.stdin.write()`.